# Mongo .save() works locally but has validation errors on Heroku remote

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, save

I am able to connect to my Mongo db and my data, save() worked locally but since pushing to Heroku I noticed saves triggers validation errors. There is nothing in the logs anywhere. I have two post routes calling the mongoose save function, I tested vs `findOneAndUpdate` in the second function to rule that out but validation error persists. I also tried to secure the post route with my middle ware but still no luck. I know I will get an error on edit with fields being undefined on render but still the save function should save to the db in the other function.

The only significant change was integrating auth0 so I thought perhaps I need to run the post route through the middle ware but that didn't seem to work either.

The payload does seem send but doesn't save to the DB, any advice on how to get more info or what I might be missing? I know its alot to digest but any ideas please?

- auth0 tenant set to production
- mongo: ip whitelisted and 0.0.0.0 and user have readwrite to all permissions - i tried admin too
- mongo db string format: mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxxxx-zylbs.azure.mongodb.net/bookingsDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority
- There are two db in the cluster, each with their unique name but same collection name so I can reference deva dn production dbs (in case that might be it).

postroutes.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Booking = mongoose.model('Booking');

    router.post('/add', /* secured(), */(req, res) => {
        insertRecord(req, res);
    });
    function insertRecord(req, res) {
        const booking = new Booking();
        booking.firstName = req.body.firstName;
        booking.lastName = req.body.lastName;
        booking.customerEmail = req.body.customerEmail;
        booking.phone = req.body.phone;
        booking.pax = req.body.pax;
        booking.tourType = req.body.tourType;
        booking.operatorName = req.body.operatorName;
        booking.dateBooked = req.body.dateBooked;
        booking.tourDate = req.body.tourDate;
        booking.pickupAddress = req.body.pickupAddress;
        booking.notes = req.body.notes;
        booking.paidStatus = req.body.paidStatus;
        booking.guidesName = req.body.guidesName;
        booking.guidesEmail = req.body.guidesEmail;
        booking.clientReminderSent = req.body.clientReminderSent;
        booking.bookingCreatedSent = req.body.bookingCreatedSent;
        booking.calendarEventCreated = req.body.calendarEventCreated;
        booking.remindGoCapeGuides = req.body.remindGoCapeGuides;
        booking.remindOperators = req.body.remindOperators;
        booking.feedbackSent = req.body.feedbackSent;
        booking.save((err, doc) => {
            if (!err) {
                //  res.redirect('/list');
                res.render('add', {
                    viewTitle: 'Add New Booking',
                    booking: req.body,
                    saveSuccessful: 'Booking Saved',
                });

                console.log('Saved!');
            } else {
                if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                    res.render('add', {
                        viewTitle: 'Add New Booking',
                        booking: req.body,
                        saveUnsuccessful: 'Not Saved: ' + err + ' Error saving booking, please try again.',
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Error during record insertion : ' + err);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    router.post('/edit', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body._id);
        updateRecord(req, res);
    });

    function updateRecord(req, res) {
        const booking = new Booking();
        booking.firstName = req.body.firstName;
        booking.lastName = req.body.lastName;
        booking.customerEmail = req.body.customerEmail;
        booking.phone = req.body.phone;
        booking.pax = req.body.pax;
        booking.tourType = req.body.tourType;
        booking.operatorName = req.body.operatorName;
        booking.dateBooked = req.body.dateBooked;
        booking.tourDate = req.body.tourDate;
        booking.pickupAddress = req.body.pickupAddress;
        booking.notes = req.body.notes;
        booking.paidStatus = req.body.paidStatus;
        booking.guidesName = req.body.guidesName;
        booking.guidesEmail = req.body.guidesEmail;
        booking.clientReminderSent = req.body.clientReminderSent;
        booking.bookingCreatedSent = req.body.bookingCreatedSent;
        booking.calendarEventCreated = req.body.calendarEventCreated;
        booking.remindGoCapeGuides = req.body.remindGoCapeGuides;
        booking.remindOperators = req.body.remindOperators;
        booking.feedbackSent = req.body.feedbackSent;

        Booking.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, {new: true}, (err, doc) =>  {
            if (!err) {
                 res.redirect('/list');
               /* res.render('edit', {
                    viewTitle: 'Edit Booking',
                    booking: req.body,
                    saveSuccessful: 'Booking Updated',
                });*/
            } else {
                if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    handleValidationError(err, req.body);
                    res.render('edit', {
                        viewTitle: 'Edit Booking',
                        booking: req.body,
                        saveUnsuccessful: 'Not Saved: Error saving booking, please try again.',
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Error during record update : ' + err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function handleValidationError(err, body) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
        for (field in err.errors) {
            switch (err.errors[field].path) {
                case 'firstName':
                    body['firstNameError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'lastName':
                    body['lastNameError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'tourType':
                    body['tourTypeError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'dateBooked':
                    body['dateBookedError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'tourDate':
                    body['tourDateError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'pax':
                    body['paxError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'phone':
                    body['phoneError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'customerEmail':
                    body['customerEmailError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'pickupAddress':
                    body['pickupAddressError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'operatorName':
                    body['operatorNameError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'paidStatus':
                    body['paidStatusError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                case 'notes':
                    body['paidStatusError'] = err.errors[field].message;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    router.post('/search/:q', function (req, res) {
        const q = req.body.q;
        res.send(q);
        console.log(q);
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

routes.js

```
router.get('/add', secured(), (req, res, next) => {
// const {_raw, _json, ...userProfile} = req.user;
res.render('add', {
viewTitle: 'Add New Booking',
booking: req.body,
});
});

router.get('/edit/:id', secured(), (req, res) => {
    Booking.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('edit', {
        viewTitle: 'Edit Booking',
        booking: doc,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  tourType: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  dateBooked: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  tourDate: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  pax: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  customerEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  pickupAddress: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  operatorName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  paidStatus: {
    type: String,
    required: 'This field is required',
  },
  notes: {
    type: String,
  },
  guidesName: {
    type: String,
  },
  guidesEmail: {
    type: String,
  },
  bookingCreatedSent: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  calendarEventCreated: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  clientReminderSent: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  remindOperators: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  remindGoCapeGuides: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  feedbackSent: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
});

// Custom validation for email
bookingSchema.path('customerEmail').validate((val) => {
  emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return emailRegex.test(val);
}, 'Invalid e-mail.');

mongoose.model('Booking', bookingSchema);
```

Any advise would be much appreciated!

UPDATE

I added `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to get additional info but when I post a form I don't see anything in the Heroku logs or anywhere else, could this be the middleware? Since the routes /add and /edit are going through the secure middleware, should the post routes be doing the same?

OK I finally got an error on the logs while switching between `body-parser` and `express.json` to test, it lead me to an error in a another module which wasn't being called correctly but was dependent on save, then due to an incorrect closure and reference it was left hanging. It seems now all is working again as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an error on the logs while switching between body-parser and express.json to test, it lead me to an error in a another module which wasn't being called correctly but was dependent on save, then due to an incorrect closure and reference it was left hanging. It seems now all is working again as expected.